# How to use iCloud Drive on iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

On the following screenshot from https://www.apple.com/icloud/icloud-drive/, it looks like I can use an iCloud app on iPhone and iPad.  But some webpage such as http://www.imore.com/how-set-and-use-icloud-drive-iphone-and-ipad says that there is no iCloud Drive app.

I hunted every where on the iPhone 5S and iPad Air which both have iOS 8 and has iCloud enabled, but I can't find such screen as in the screenshot below.

So how do I go to the screenshot as below?  I upload a PDF file, a picture, and an mp4 file on my Macbook using the Chrome browser on www.icloud.com, but can't access those files just like how I would use DropBox or [Copy](https://copy.com?r=EkirEQ) (which has 15GB free).
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Those screenshots are from inside Pages**, an app which contains support for iCloud Drive and allows you to select any Pages file inside any of your folders in iCloud Drive.

You can't just 'access' the files in iCloud Drive in iOS like you can on Dropbox. You need to use an app which supports that filetype and iCloud Drive to be able to open the files.

Comment: Worth noting that many apps don't support iCloud drive yet, including some of Apple's own apps, such as iBooks (http://www.verschoren.com/blog/2014/11/22/ibooks-and-icloud-drive).

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 9 we have an iCloud Drive app. (It basically turns the DocumentPicker interface into its own app.) In iOS 9, the iCloud Drive app starts off hidden by default. You can turn it on at any time in the iCloud Drive Settings.

**How to turn on the iCloud Drive app in iOS 9**

1. Launch the Settings app from your Home screen.
2. Tap on iCloud.
3. Tap on iCloud Drive.
4. Switch Show on Home Screen to On.
5. Click the Home button to exit Settings.
6. Launch the iCloud Drive app from your Home screen.

If you ever decide you want to hide it again, you can repeat the same process and switch it to Off.

**Note**: On iOS 10, if you want to hide the iCloud Drive app, you can remove it from your Home screen the same way you would delete an app.

Answer (score 0):

There is an iOS app called Documents by Riddle in the app store. This app includes support for browsing and opening files from iCloud Drive. There is also an app called Cloud Drive Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly access [iCloud drive with apps](http://www.iphoneups.com/2015/01/icloud-drive-apps-3-ways-to-explore.html) in your iOS8 devices. You can do it by using Pages or Document 5 but not with Cloud Drive Explorer as this app has been removed from iTunes for compatibility issue.  Rather there is a wonderful new third party app available to perform this task.

Answer (score -1):

I believe those screenshots are of a third party app called "Cloud Drive Explorer."  It can be downloaded in the app store